export 'Auth' (imported as 'Auth') was not found in 'aws-amplify'
I shouldn't import Auth from 'aws-amplify'
I'm trying to do Change password in react.
But it is giving error when
I make these calls
const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
await Auth.changePassword(user, oldPassword, newPassword);
my code:
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify'; 

import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

import { Button, TextField, View, Heading, Text } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';

import Layout from '../components/Layout';

const ChangePassword = () => {
    const [oldPassword, setOldPassword] = useState('');

    const [newPassword, setNewPassword] = useState('');

    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');

    const [successMessage, setSuccessMessage] = useState('');

    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const { t } = useTranslation();

    const handleChangePassword = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setErrorMessage('');
        setSuccessMessage('');

        try {
            const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
            await Auth.changePassword(user, oldPassword, newPassword);
            setSuccessMessage(t('Password changed successfully!'));
            setTimeout(() => navigate('/'), 3000);
        } catch (error) {
            setErrorMessage(t(error.message || 'Failed to change password'));
        }
    };

    return (
        <Layout>
            <div data-amplify-authenticator="" data-variation="default">
                <div data-amplify-container="">
                    <div style={{ padding: "1.5rem", textAlign: "center" }}>
                        <Heading level={3}>{t('Change Password')}</Heading>
                    </div>
                    <div data-amplify-router="">
                        <form
                            data-amplify-form=""
                            data-amplify-authenticator-changepassword=""
                            onSubmit={handleChangePassword}
                            method="post"
                        >
                            <fieldset className="amplify-flex" style={{ flexDirection: "column" }}>
                                <h3 className="amplify-heading amplify-heading--3"></h3>
                                <div className="amplify-flex" style={{ flexDirection: "column" }}>
                                    <TextField
                                    label={t("Current Password")}
                                    placeholder={t("Enter your current password")}
                                    type="password"
                                    value={oldPassword}
                                    onChange={(e) => setOldPassword(e.target.value)}
                                    required
                                    />
                                
                                    <TextField
                                    label={t("New Password")}
                                    placeholder={t("Enter your new password")}
                                    type="password"
                                    value={newPassword}
                                    onChange={(e) => setNewPassword(e.target.value)}
                                    required                                 
                                    />
                                    {errorMessage && <Text color="red">{errorMessage}</Text>}
                                    {successMessage && <Text color="green">{successMessage}</Text>}
                                </div>
                                <div className="amplify-flex" style={{ flexDirection: "column" }}>
                                    <Button
                                    className="amplify-button amplify-field-group__control amplify-button--primary"
                                    type="submit"
                                    >
                                    {t("Change Password")}
                                    </Button>
                                <div
                                    className="amplify-flex"
                                    style={{ flexDirection: "column", alignItems: "center" }}
                                    ></div>
                                </div>
                                <p className="amplify-text"></p>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>;    
        </Layout>
    );
};

export default ChangePassword;


my package.json
    {
  
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/auth": "^6.3.15",
    "@aws-amplify/ui": "^6.0.17",
    "@aws-amplify/ui-react": "^6.2.0",
    "@aws-amplify/ui-react-liveness": "^3.1.4",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^6.3.12",
    "aws-amplify": "^6.5.3",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1664.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
    "i18next": "^23.12.2",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^8.0.0",
    "i18next-http-backend": "^2.5.2",
    "jquery": "^3.7.1",
    "jquery-validation": "^1.20.1",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.10.4",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.52.1",
    "react-i18next": "^14.1.3",
    "react-icons": "^5.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.25.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-table": "^7.8.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}

Would you like to be able to access these 2 methods
const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
await Auth.changePassword(user, oldPassword, newPassword);
